# Is it possible to chain non-scope for model query?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Let me explain via example.

```
Model::staticMethod()->localScope()->get(); # works
Model::staticMethod()->nonStaticMethod()->get(); # fail
```

I'm a right to assume that your model methods have to be static and if you would like to chain more methods the following ones need to be local scope methods?

Let's say I want to have a query which chains 3 methods and the sequence is optional, meaning

```
Model::method1()->method2()->method3();
Model::method2()->method1()->method3();
```

How I would go about setting up my model?

Comment: As long as your methods return the query builder, you should be able to chain them

Comment: Hi @AngadDubey, would you be able to provide an example as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

You're correct, if the staticMethod starts a query you will only be able to use local scope methods from that point onwards. You can work around this by adding your own static methods to the Model class that actually return an instance of your Model so you can set it up from there.
(Or use static methods like create() that already do this for you.)

The reason for this is that most static methods don't actually return an instance of the Model class but an instance of the Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder class (https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html).

The Builder's __call() magic method intercepts all functions that don't actually exist on the Builder class, and then uses the function name to perform all kinds of magic.

In case you're interested, the code actually implementing the scopes is the following 3 lines in that __call method:

```
if (method_exists($this->model, $scope = 'scope'.ucfirst($method))) {
        return $this->callScope([$this->model, $scope], $parameters);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Schalks. Would you be able to provide an example for _You can work around this by adding your own static methods to the Model class that actually return an instance of your Model so you can set it up from there. (Or use static methods like create() that already do this for you.)_